# PHP Search Multidimensional Array for Duplicate Values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Foo] => Bar
                [Foo2] => String1
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Foo] => Bar
                [Foo2] => String2
            )

    )
```

While the one I'm working with is a lot larger, that's the general form of it. I'm trying to look at each value relative to Foo, and if there is a repeat in one of the arrays, take the subsequent Foo2 value and "push" it to a new array, essentially looking like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Foo] => Bar
                [Foo2] => String1,
                           String2 
        )

)
```

Basically I just want to know if this is even possible!!

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: the resulting array you have displayed is impossible - associative arrays can not have same keys

Comment: I have edited it, this is what I meant-

Comment: @CharlotteDunois you should post your answer.

Comment: Something like this maybe? https://3v4l.org/qlWN5 Unless you give us more sample data (and the desired output), there is no certainity that this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `isset` and `array_values` functions:

```
$grouped = [];
foreach ($arr as $v) {  // $arr is your initial array
    $foo = $v[0]['Foo'];
    if (!isset($grouped[$foo])) {
        $grouped[$foo] = $v[0];
    } else {
        $grouped[$foo]['Foo2'] .= "," . $v[0]['Foo2'];
    }
}
$result = array_values($grouped);
print_r($result);
```

[DEMO link](https://eval.in/629150)

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to use a for loop within a while loop:

Go through the input array with a while (while the input array length>0)

Copy the first array with Foo and Foo2  into the (initially empty) output array

Use the for loop to go through the input array from the second position onwards to find similar instances of Foo, when you find one:

a) Copy the value of Foo2 and append it to the output array at Foo2 (the last array within the output array).

b) Unset the array with a duplicate instance of Foo from the input array (since it is now in the output array)

Then unset the first array within the input array (since all instances are now in the output array) and break.

At the end the input array will be empty and the output array will be sorted as per your request.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of a code example, my phone isn't cooperating